# Facing issue with MFA while adding account to Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

I am getting error while adding account to yodlee, below are the steps which i am doing for add site based account.

1.I am adding account by calling addSiteAccount1.

2.After adding account i am able to get MFA for account by calling getMFAResponseForSite API

3.When we putting MFA by calling putMFARequestForSite API we are getting error in json response

And the all responses which i am getting are 
1.response for addsiteaccount1 is

```
{"siteAccountId":12803756,"isCustom":false,"credentialsChangedTime":1442572129,"siteRefreshInfo":{"siteRefreshStatus":{"siteRefreshStatusId":1,"siteRefreshStatus":"REFRESH_TRIGGERED"},"siteRefreshMode":{"refreshModeId":1,"refreshMode":"MFA"},"updateInitTime":1442572129,"nextUpdate":1442573029,"code":801,"suggestedFlow":{"suggestedFlowId":2,"suggestedFlow":"REFRESH"},"noOfRetry":0,"isMFAInputRequired":true,"siteAddStatus":{"siteAddStatusId":13,"siteAddStatus":"ADD_IN_PROGRESS"}},"siteInfo":{"popularity":0,"siteId":16486,"orgId":1148,"defaultDisplayName":"Dag Site SecurityQA","defaultOrgDisplayName":"Demo Bank","enabledContainers":[{"containerName":"bank","assetType":1},{"containerName":"credits","assetType":2}],"baseUrl":"http://64.14.28.129/dag/index.do","loginForms":[],"isHeld":false,"isCustom":false,"mfaType":{"typeId":4,"typeName":"SECURITY_QUESTION"},"siteSearchVisibility":true,"isAlreadyAddedByUser":true,"isOauthEnabled":false,"hdLogoLastModified":0,"isHdLogoAvailable":false},"created":"2015-09-18T03:28:49-0700","retryCount":0,"disabled":false,"isAgentError":false,"isSiteError":false,"isUARError":false}
```

2.Response for getMFAResponseForSite is

```
{"isMessageAvailable":true,"fieldInfo":{"questionAndAnswerValues":[{"question":"What is the name of your state?","questionFieldType":"label","responseFieldType":"text","isRequired":"true","sequence":1,"metaData":"QUESTION_1"},{"question":"What is the name of your first school","questionFieldType":"label","responseFieldType":"text","isRequired":"true","sequence":2,"metaData":"QUESTION_2"}],"numOfMandatoryQuestions":-1,"mfaFieldInfoType":"SECURITY_QUESTION"},"timeOutTime":46320,"itemId":0,"memSiteAccId":12792909,"retry":false}
```

3. And when I send MFA information I am getting following exception

   {"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"com.yodlee.core.InvalidSiteAccountException","referenceCode":"_dc15c156-100b-4049-a75d-dbfa2250b22f","message":"Argument
   value not found: 12792909"}

Can anyone tell me where i am using wrong api or flow as mentioned at [AddSiteAccount API flow](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the MFA for which you are trying is Q/A. And assuming you are using putMFARequestForSite, while the error which you have received is happening because the memSiteAccId which you have provided is incorrect, as exception itself says it- "com.yodlee.core.InvalidSiteAccountException". Please pass the correct memSiteAccId, which I can see from the response of addSiteAccount1 is- 12803756.

Comment: thanks @Apoorv for your answer and you are right i was passing wrong siteaccountId now everything is working.